# AWS Lambda. Move file to tmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, shutil

After hours trying to figure out why I cant rename a file, It turns out in lambda that you cannot rename a file unless it is in the `/tmp/` directory.

My structure is like so :

```
-lambda_function.py
-/pics/
------ photo.jpg.
```

I am trying to change the name of `photo.jpg`.

How do I move that photo from that directory to `/tmp/photo.jpg` ?

I have tried using:

```
shutil.move("./pics/photo.jpg", "/tmp/photo.jpg")
```

but I get the error:

> "[Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't rename a file, you can't delete or move it either. Also probably `./pics` and `/tmp` are not even on the same filesystem.

You can probably `shutil.copy()` it and forget about the old one.